# Nested RecyclerView too tall

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView named DogRecyclerView. I have another RecyclerView called FoodRecyclerView. FoodRecyclerView happens to be one of the many layouts of DogRecyclerView (i.e. one of the `ViewHolder`s). DogRecyclerView is a list. FoodRecyclerView is actually as below. The problem is that the view below is not wrapping the content but rather it is taking more height than it should. How might I fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="This is a Label that I am testing right now"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/food_grid"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So as you can see I lied a little. The nested view is actually a LinearLayout that wraps a RecyclerView and a TextView. Deee-tails...

I left out something oh so important: my LayoutManager is as below:

```
public class NestedGridLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager {

    public NestedGridLayoutManager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    public NestedGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount) {
        super(context, spanCount);
    }

    public NestedGridLayoutManager(Context context, int spanCount, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
        super(context, spanCount, orientation, reverseLayout);
    }

    private int[] mMeasuredDimension = new int[2];

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        final int widthMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(widthSpec);
        final int heightMode = View.MeasureSpec.getMode(heightSpec);
        final int widthSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(widthSpec);
        final int heightSize = View.MeasureSpec.getSize(heightSpec);
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getItemCount(); i++) {
            measureScrapChild(recycler, i,
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(i, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                    mMeasuredDimension);

            if (getOrientation() == HORIZONTAL) {
                width = width + mMeasuredDimension[0];
                if (i == 0) {
                    height = mMeasuredDimension[1];
                }
            } else {
                height = height + mMeasuredDimension[1];
                if (i == 0) {
                    width = mMeasuredDimension[0];
                }
            }
        }
        switch (widthMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                width = widthSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        switch (heightMode) {
            case View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                height = heightSize;
            case View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
            case View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
        }

        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    private void measureScrapChild(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, int position, int widthSpec,
                                   int heightSpec, int[] measuredDimension) {
        View view = recycler.getViewForPosition(position);
        if (view != null) {
            RecyclerView.LayoutParams p = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
            int childWidthSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(widthSpec,
                    getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight(), p.width);
            int childHeightSpec = ViewGroup.getChildMeasureSpec(heightSpec,
                    getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom(), p.height);
            view.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
            measuredDimension[0] = view.getMeasuredWidth() + p.leftMargin + p.rightMargin;
            measuredDimension[1] = view.getMeasuredHeight() + p.bottomMargin + p.topMargin;
            recycler.recycleView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's as if the LinearLayout wants to double whatever the actual content height is. Not actually, but almost. Also the nested RecyclerView is a grid (i.e. GridLayoutManager)

Answer (score -1):

Support for `WRAP_CONTENT` and generally auto-measuring the size of the `RecyclerView` based on its content is one of the headlines features of the [Support Library 23.2.0 release](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html). As long as you are using an included `LayoutManager`, you should get this behavior for free.